# How much data we can pass through URLConnection.?

Tags: java, json, urlconnection

I am passing 10 students information from one Application to Other application in json format.I have to send 25 lacs studends information from one application to other application. I want to know, how much size of data i can send ? how many students i can send in json format.?
Below is code from sender application.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        for (Student student : listStudent) {        
            JSONObject studentJSON = new JSONObject();
            studentJSON.put("First Name", student.getFirstName());
            studentJSON.put("Last Name", student.getLastName());
            jArray.put(studentJSON);
        }
        jsonObject.put("StudentArray", jArray);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(jsonObject.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Below is code from receiver application.

```
     URL url = new URL("http:"//xyz.com);
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
     JSONObject object = null ;
     String line=null;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
     {
       object= new JSONObject(line);
     }
```

Comment: Depends on the sever on which you are sending the data...

Comment: Are you getting an error or is this just a general question?

Comment: General question. I have done development of it. but i want to clear my doubt , so that going ahead it will not break  if  one application sends more (25 lacs) user information at a time in json format.

Answer (score 0):

`URLConnection` supports the [HTTP Specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) for HTTP connections. I haven't really seen a max number of bytes that can be transferred via HTTP, but the size must match the header Content-Length if present. Otherwise bytes will continue to be read until the connection is closed.

`URLConnection` treats the value of Content-Length as an `int` in [Java 1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength()) and earlier or a `long` in [Java 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong()) and later, which would suggest that the maximum supported number of bytes in the body would be 2^31-1 bytes or 2^63-1 bytes, respectively, so long as Content-Length is being set.

Comment: The `Content-length` is set automatically. It isn't a matter of 'so long as `Content-length` is being set'.

Comment: According to the spec, [Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) is not required and there is even a special section for determining length if it is not provided. If you're speaking specifically to Java web servers could you provide a link to support your claim?